# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a flask project.
The structure of the project is as follows:

```
├── project
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── main
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   └── users
└── run.py
```

**run.py**

```
from project import create_app
app = create_app()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from project.config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)

    from project.main.routes import main
    from project.users.routes import users

    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    return app
```

**models.py**

```
from flask import current_app
from project import db

class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

My problem is when I open the terminal in `project/project` directory and open a python prompt and import Users or Post from models.py, it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aman/Desktop/websites/project/project/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from project import db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

But it's clear that project does exist and is also a python module since, I have created a **init**.py file in project directory.
Please help me.

Comment: Your traceback does not fit the code. The module names differ.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a typing mistake. I have edited the traceback

Comment: I guess you have edited out the error now. Always present **original** code and error messages.

Comment: It's the original code as well as error messages. I have mistakenly changed it when I am writing the question and so I corrected it.

Comment: Any ideas please????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I have found that I was trying to import db and Users from inside the project module. When I tried to access db and Users from outside directory of project modules, I finally succeed.

Initial directory I am importing db:
`/home/aman/Desktop/websites/project/project`
which gives error.

Now, directory I am importing db:
`/home/aman/Desktop/websites/project`
which works good.